# Rxjs6: Can't handle error in async function

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

`getComments` is async function. When it returns an error, I want to handle it through `catchError`. But I always execute `map()` and never execute `catchError`.

Why and How to fix this?

```
from(getComments(action.payload.url)).pipe(
  map((comments: IComments[]) => commentsActions.fetch.done({ params: action.payload.url, result: { comments } })),
  // TODO: 以下ではError handlingができない
  catchError(error => of(commentsActions.fetch.failed({ params: action.payload.url, error: { hasError: true } }))),
),
```

and

```
export const getComments = async (url: string) => {
  return await fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(comments => comments)
    .catch((e: string) => throwError(e));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from the second block of code you are using a **async function** but also you are using the `.then` key word? `await` keyword already returns the promise that is resolved. You just need to declare a variable for example `const response = await fetch(url)`

Comment: when does error happen? how do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

I handle error with `ajax` and it works.

https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.md